# rotate direction on 3 axes direction

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

How do I rotate a direction, given as (heading, pitch, roll) in the direction of (dHeading, 0, 0),  or (0, dPitch, 0),

For example, The direction is looking down (heading = 0, pitch = 90, roll = 0), and I would like to rotate in (0, -90), so the composite direction would be (0, 0, 0). In this simple case I can just add the two vectors, but i'm interested in the general solution.

Thanks,
Eyal

Answer (score 0):

As the order in which you carry out the change in heading and pitch affects the resultant roll of the body, you will need to specify what you actually want to achieve. I would suggest getting familiar with Euler [transforms](https://youtu.be/A6lf8t9WXn8).

Comment: Thanks for the video ! I have corrected my question.